# Should I have a field that points to another record on the same table or is it better to have a separate table and duplicate data?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am design a table in my database that should be like this:

**Table: Companies**

```
ID_Company  Name    City      Parent_Company

    1       Alpha   Paris          3

    2       Beta    New York       3

    3       Delta   London         4

    4       Gamma   Sidney         -
```

The field "ParentCompany" will store "ID_Company" values.

Is this a good design or should I create a separate table "Parent_Companies" and duplicate the data?

Comment: Why would you want to duplicate the data ? The whole point of databases is to avoid this. Just create a foreign key referencing the Id_Company.

Comment: Yes it is a good design.

Comment: yes, good design, add a foreign key to enforce the constraints

Comment: I concur with others and would just like to point out that duplicating data within a database is generally a bad idea (because if two copies go out of sync, you have effectively corrupted the data). In fact, the whole purpose of database normalization is removal of redundancies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is good design, a table referencing itself is perfectly good. it is the way you design hierarchies.

Add a foreign key for the 'Parent_Company' column to your ID_Company  column to enforce constraints and have database integrity.

```
ALTER TABLE [Companies]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentCompanu] FOREIGN KEY([Parent_Company])
REFERENCES [Companies] ([ID_Company])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using common Design Pattern - Self Referencing table.
Nothing bad here